# Git commit access to part of a repository

Tags: git, commit

Say I have a repo with two directories, high_level/ and low_level/.
I have a contributor who wants commit access, but I only feel comfortable (and they only want to) letting them touch the high_level/ directory.

It would be too much of an inconvenience having to run around reverting crazy commits.

Is it possible to do this without splitting the repository up?

Comment: Consider using submodules.

Comment: Git doesn't regulate this, so you'd look at outside tools like Gitolite for it.  That said, perhaps you should look into only accepting patches from that committer instead, so they don't have to have write access to your repository (and they can clone it and do what they deem necessary to their own, private copy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *is* possible to do this with a pre-receive hook, but there's nothing built-in for it.

To do it in a pre-receive hook, have your hook scan the proposed label updates, e.g.:

```
#! /bin/sh
...

while read oldsha newsha fullref; do
    verify $oldsha $newsha $fullref || {
        echo "$fullref: $oldsha -> $newsha update rejected"
        exit 1
    }
done
```

You still have to write the verify() function:

```
NULL_SHA1=0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 # 40 0's

reftype() {
    case $1 in
    $NULL_SHA1) echo none;;
    *) git cat-file -t $1;;
}

verify() {
    local oldsha=$1 newsha=$2 fullref=$3
    local otype=$(reftype $oldsha) ntype=$(reftype $newsha)
    local update_type

    case $otype,$ntype in
    none,*) update_type=create;;
    *,none) update_type=delete;;
    *,*) update_type=update;;
    esac

    # now if update_type is create or delete, check permissions
    # but if update_type is update, check revisions
    verify_$update_type $oldsha $newsha $fullref
}
```

(The above can be fancier, e.g., can check for annotated tag create/delete, and you can check the ref-type vs the object-type.)

This "verify" just returns whatever the corresponding more-specific verify_create, verify_delete or verify_update returns.  So you have to write those:

```
verify_create() {
    local oldsha=$1 newsha=$2 fullref=$3

    # only $USER = wilma is allowed to create
    [ "$USER" = wilma ] && return 0
    echo "you ($USER) are not allowed to create things"
    return 1
}

verify_delete() {
    local oldsha=$1 newsha=$2 fullref=$3

    # only $USER = fred is allowed to delete
    [ "$USER" = fred ] && return 0
    echo "you ($USER) are not allowed to delete things"
    return 1
}
```

Now we're down to verify_update:

```
verify_update() {
    local oldsha=$1 newsha=$2 fullref=$3
    local shortref rev

    case "$fullref" in
    refs/heads/*) 
        # a branch
        shortref=${fullref#refs/heads/}
        ;;

    *)  # everything else - only barney is allowed to do those
        # (and we don't check any further)
        [ "$USER" = barney ] && return 0
        echo "you ($USER) are not allowed to modify $fullref"
        return 1
        ;;
    esac

    # user betty is restricted on branches that do not start with betty*
    # everyone else is unrestricted
    [ "$USER" = betty ] || return 0
    case "$shortref" in
    betty*) return 0;;
    esac

    # 1. betty is NOT allowed to REMOVE commits, even with force-push
    if [ $(git rev-list --count $newsha..$oldsha) -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "commit to branch $shortref would remove some revs"
        return 1
    fi

    # 2. betty is not allowed to make certain changes
    # e.g., first we forbid merges:
    if [ $(git rev-list --count --min-parents=2 \
            $oldsha..$newsha) -ne 0 ]; then
         echo "you ($USER) are not allowed to push a merge"
         return 1
    fi
    # then we look at each commit
    for rev in $(git rev-list $oldsha..$newsha); do
         check_betty_commit $rev "$shortref" || return 1
    done
}
```

Whew, we're almost there.  Just need to check the changes betty is proposing:

```
check_betty_commit() {
    local rev=$1 shortref="$2"

    # unfortunately, pipe to a loop causes the loop to
    # run in a sub-shell, so it's a bit complicated here.
    git diff-tree -r --no-renames --name-only --no-commit-id $rev |
    (retval=0; while read pathname; do
        case "$pathname" in
        forbidden/path/*)
            echo "branch $shortref: $rev modifies $pathname"
            retval=1
            ;;
        esac
    done
    exit $retval) || return 1
}
```

Note: most of the above is quite un-tested.

Hard-coding the user names is also probably not good.  But this should give you some ideas on how to script this, if you really want to go this way.

Incidentally, there is a different (but more-tested) script [here](http://web.torek.net/torek/git/pre-receive.sh.txt) that implements a limited set of per-user access controls based on settings in the repository itself, rather than hard-coding them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any way to do that out-of-the-box. You could probably write a hook script to do it at the main repo, but it feels like the right way to do this is to not allow this contributor to commit to the repository at all.

Instead, have them make commits to their own repository, then you can pull the ones you want into the main repo. This way, you have complete control over how and when his commits come into your repo (or not, if they don't meet your standards).

If you really need this functionality, the "submodule" feature @SLaks suggested may meet your needs; you can essentially treat the "high_level" as a separate project that you map into your "low_level" repository. Then he can commit to the high_level repository, and you can pull those commits into your low_level repository. See http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules

Comment: Yes, that's what is being done now, but it doesn't answer the question. :)

Comment: The answer is "no". ;) The "submodule" feature @SLaks suggested may meet your needs; you can essentially treat the "high_level" as a separate project that you map into your "low_level" repository. Then he can commit to the high_level repository, and you can pull those commits into your low_level repository. See http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules

Comment: Well, you could add it as an answer then. :-)